# Google reCAPTCHA floating notice not displaying fully

Tags: javascript, css, recaptcha

If you go to this site (https://www.networkhq.org/AutoServiceExpertApplication), you will notice the Google recaptcha notice floating in the bottom right corner of the screen.  However, you will also notice that even though the entire slide out exists, it looks like the css is not fully rendering inside of the slideout.  Has anyone else seen this behavior before?

The recaptcha itself is working perfectly fine.  It appears to be solely a display problem.

Comment: Try to increase the height of the iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your PublicSite.css you have:

```
iframe {
    padding: 0 0 2em 0;
}
```

If you remove the 2em bottom padding your captcha image will show completely.

Comment: You, sir, are a gentleman and a scholar.  Thank you very much.  I could not, for the life of me, figure out where the disconnect was.